# ETL script I/O can cause disk damage?

Tags: database, io, etl

I have a php script that load data from a csv files (more than 600 mb of csv files) every day on oracle database , I remark that I/O is high on the server when the script is running because files exists on the same oracle server and I wonder if that I/O can cause disk damage.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherently bad about doing this.  Using the disk through normal methods cannot cause damage to it, apart from the normal usage wear and tear.  Hard drives do wear out over time, and heavy usage can cause them to wear out faster, but I would not call that damage.  Similarly flash based SSD's will wear out after a certain number of writes, so more writes will wear them out faster, but again this is normal wear and not damage.

It may be faster to read the files and perform and queries from another machine, but doing it on one machine will not damage anything.